# awk compare adjacent lines and print based on if statements

Tags: awk

I have one file with multiple lines (reads from a genome) and they are sorted (based on their locations). Now I want to loop over these lines and if multiple lines have the same ID (column 4), I want to keep either keep the first, if column 3 is a plus or the last, if column three is a minus. This is m code but it seems like my variable (lastID) is not properly updated after each line.
Tips are much appreciated.

```
awk 'BEGIN {lastline=""; lastID=""}
{if ($lastline != "" && $4 != $lastID)
        {print $lastline; lastline=""};
if ($3 == "+" && $4 != $lastID)
        {print $0; lastline=""}
else if ($3 == "+" && $4 == $lastID)
        {lastli=""}
else if ($3 == "-")
        {lastline=$0}; 
lastID=$4
}' file
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and special thanks for sharing your efforts in form of code. To make more clear picture for question its always recommended to add samples of input and expected output so kindly do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Answer (score 2):

To access the value of a variable in awk you just use the name of the variable, just like in C and most other Algol-based languages. You don't stick a `$` in front of it like you would with shell. Try changing:

```
$lastline != "" && $4 != $lastID
```

to:

```
lastline != "" && $4 != lastID
```

etc.

This might be what you're trying to do (your BEGIN section was doing nothing useful so I just removed it):

```
awk '
    (lastline != "") && ($4 != lastID) {
        print lastline
        lastline=""
    }
    $3 == "+" {
        if ($4 == lastID) {
            lastli=""
        }
        else {
            print $0
            lastline=""
        }
    }
    $3 == "-" {
        lastline=$0
    } 
    { lastID=$4 }
' file
```

When formatted sensibly like that you can see that `lastli` is never used anywhere except where it's set to `""` so that's probably a bug - maybe it's supposed to `lastline` in which case it can be made common rather than being set in both the `if` and `else` legs?

Answer (score 0):

you may want to utilize `awk`'s own `condition{statement}` structure.  Note that code layout is not universally accepted but I find it easier to read for short statements.

```
$ awk '$lastline!="" && $4 != $lastID {print lastline; lastline=""}
       $3=="+"       && $4 != $lastID {print; lastline=""}
       $3=="+"       && $4 == $lastID {lastli=""}
       $3=="-"                        {lastline=$0}
                                      {lastID=$4}' file
```